# `using` directives inside C++ headers

Tags: c++

I am puzzled by the following sentence found in the book *Accelerated C++* by Koenig and Moo:

```
// median.h
#include <vector>
double median(std::vector<double>);
```

> In this example, we use the qualified name for `std::vector` because
>   we have no way of knowing how the user of our function wants to refer
>   to `std::vector`. Users of our code might not want a
>   `using`-declaration for `vector`. If we write one in our header, then
>   all programs that include our header get a `using std::vector`
>   declaration, regardless of whether they wanted it. Header files should
>   use fully qualified names rather than `using`-declarations.

I don't think I understand this passage. If we had a `using std::vector` declaration in our header, and the whole program including the header gets the same declaration, this could be a problem only if the user is redefining the `vector` class, isn't it? But then our `median` function would still require a `vector` from the standard library, so if the user wanted to use `median` on a newly defined `vector`, it would give an error at compile time.

Comment: Not "redefining the vector class", defining a different class, in a different namespace, with the name "vector". If we didn't care, the standard could have put vector in the global namespace directly.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

Comment: If you had `using std::vector` and I would include your header, I couldn't do `stop using std::vector` back in my code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To understand the words, it is necessary to understand what a `using` directive like `using namespace std` does.

When it sees a name like `vector` the compiler, by default, looks for `vector` within the current context (i.e. in your example, that is in the "global namespace" or, equivalently in `::`).   If it doesn't find a candidate match  (i.e. something named `vector`) in that search it issues a diagnostic, and compilation ceases.

The `using namespace std` causes the compiler to look in namespace `std` for matching names.   If it finds an unambiguous match then that name is used.

The problem comes in if there is another `using` directive, such as `using namespace foo` in effect.  For example;

```
 using namespace std;
 #include "foo.h"
 using namespace foo;
 #include "median.h"
```

Now consider what happens if `foo.h` specifies a templated something named `vector` within namespace `foo`.    Assume that `median.h` has

```
double median(vector<double>);
```

Because of the two `using` directives, the compiler looks in both `std` and `foo` for a name `vector`.    If it finds a match in both namespaces, then it has two candidate matching names, `foo::vector` and `std::vector`.

If both of those names are equally good matches to `vector`, then the code has a diagnosable error due to ambiguity.   The compilation will fail.    There is no rule that makes the compiler consider a match in namespace `std` is better than one in namespace `foo`, or vice versa.

The next problem is that there is no way to undo the effect of a `using` directive (e.g. with other `using` directives or declarations).   The only way to get the code to compile in such a case is to change the declaration of `median()` to

```
double median(std::vector<double>);
```

Rather than going through all of that, Koenig and Moo are advocating using the full name `std::vector<double>` from the start, rather than messing with `using` directives in the header.    Doing that allows other programmers, who use the header file,  to employ `using` directives or declarations if they choose, but does not require them to do so.

Note:  the above is an over-simplification.   There are quite a few detailed rules that govern how a compiler finds candidates names, and then determines how good a match they are.

Answer (score 6):

If the header file was:

```
#include <vector>
using std::vector;
double median(vector<double>);
```

This would tell all compilation units (e.g. cpp files) which include `median.h` that the function `median` accepts `std::vector` and at the same time makes `std::vector` accessible with unqualified lookup `vector` in those compilation units.

If a compilation unit had access to another unqualified `vector`, there would be a name conflict and a build error. The function `median` would never receive a type that is not `std::vector` even if the name of that type was also `vector`.

It's a good idea to avoid `using` declarations in header files because it's a cause for creating name conflicts.